# Temperature in a vacuum made in the lab

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, vacuum, equilibrium

Is the thermal energy of a vacuum 0?

And, how close to a perfect vacuum can we make in the lab?

Comment: Have you read about quantum mechanics and the uncertainty principle? , also  the joule is the SI unit of measurement for energy of all kinds including chemical, thermal and electrical energy,    so could I suggest you edit your question to include it. Small thing but it's important to include units. Regards

Comment: Temperature is a funny thing when you talk about vacuum. You always have some electromagnetic fields flying around (strength depends on temperature of the walls of the vacuum chamber and how well it's shielded from the outside) so if the thing you are about couples to electromagnetic waves then the temperature of that thing is the same as the walls of the chamber.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best vacuum we can make is about 10^-12 Pa. Atmospheric pressure is about 10^5 Pa, so it's 17 orders of magnitude lower pressure. The best vacuum recorded is the intergalactic void, at about 10^-17 Pa. Even if you managed to remove all matter, there would still be energy from any light or electric fields.